# python matplotlib's gridspec unable to reduce gap between subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am using GridSpec to plot subplots within a subplot to show images.

In the example code below, I am creating a 1x2 subplot where each subplot axes contains 3x3 subplot (subplot within the first subplot).

3x3 subplot is basically showing an image cut into 9 square pieces arranged into 3x3 formation. I don't want any spacing between image pieces, so I set both `wspace` and `hspace` to 0. Weirdly enough, the resulting output subplots show vertical gap between rows.

I tried setting `hspace` to negative value to reduce vertical spacing between the rows, but it results in rows overlapping. Is there a more convenient way to achieve this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image

flower = load_sample_image('flower.jpg')
img = Image.fromarray(flower)
img = img.crop((100, 100, 325, 325))

# Create tiles - cuts image to 3x3 square tiles
n_tiles = 9
tile_size = float(img.size[0]) / 3 # assumes square tile
tiles = [None] * n_tiles
for n in range(n_tiles):
    row = n // 3 
    col = n % 3

    # compute tile coordinates in term of the image (0,0) is top left corner of the image
    left = col * tile_size
    upper = row * tile_size
    right = left + tile_size
    lower = upper + tile_size
    tile_coord = (int(left), int(upper), int(right), int(lower))
    tile = img.crop(tile_coord)
    tiles[n] = tile
    
# plot subplot of subplot using gridspec
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 3))
outer = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 3, wspace=1)

# image shown as 3x3 grid of image tiles
inner = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(3, 3, subplot_spec=outer[0], wspace=0, hspace=0)
for j in range(len(tiles_tensor)):
    ax1 = plt.Subplot(fig, inner[j], xticks=[], yticks=[])
    ax1.imshow(tiles[j])
    fig.add_subplot(ax1)

# image shown as 3x3 grid of image tiles
inner = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(3, 3, subplot_spec=outer[1], wspace=0, hspace=0)
for j in range(len(data)):
    ax2 = plt.Subplot(fig, inner[j], xticks=[], yticks=[])
    ax2.imshow(tiles[j])
    fig.add_subplot(ax2)
```

Comment: just throwing it out there... I prefer to use plt.axes to make subplots, you can explicitly state the size plt.axes(left, bottom, width, height)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that `imshow` defaults to `aspect='equal'`. This forces the small tiles to be square. But the subplots aren't square, so 9 square tiles together can't nicely fill the subplot.

An easy solution is to turn off the square aspect ratio via `imshow(..., aspect='auto')`. To get the subplots more squarely, the `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` settings can be adapted.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image

flower = load_sample_image('flower.jpg')
img = Image.fromarray(flower)
img = img.crop((100, 100, 325, 325))

# Create tiles - cuts image to 3x3 square tiles
n_tiles = 9
tile_size = float(img.size[0]) / 3  # assumes square tile
tiles = [None] * n_tiles
for n in range(n_tiles):
    row = n // 3
    col = n % 3

    # compute tile coordinates in term of the image (0,0) is top left corner of the image
    left = col * tile_size
    upper = row * tile_size
    right = left + tile_size
    lower = upper + tile_size
    tile_coord = (int(left), int(upper), int(right), int(lower))
    tile = img.crop(tile_coord)
    tiles[n] = tile

# plot subplot of subplot using gridspec
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 3))
outer = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2, wspace=1, left=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, bottom=0.1)

titles = [f'Subplot {j+1}' for j in range(outer.nrows * outer.ncols) ]
for j in range(len(titles)):
    ax = plt.Subplot(fig, outer[j], xticks=[], yticks=[])
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.set_title(titles[j])
    fig.add_subplot(ax)


# image shown as 3x3 grid of image tiles
inner = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(3, 3, subplot_spec=outer[0], wspace=0, hspace=0)
for j in range(len(tiles)):
    ax1 = plt.Subplot(fig, inner[j], xticks=[], yticks=[])
    ax1.imshow(tiles[j], aspect='auto')
    fig.add_subplot(ax1)

# image shown as 3x3 grid of image tiles
inner = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(3, 3, subplot_spec=outer[1], wspace=0, hspace=0)
for j in range(len(tiles)):
    ax2 = plt.Subplot(fig, inner[j], xticks=[], yticks=[])
    ax2.imshow(tiles[j], aspect='auto')
    fig.add_subplot(ax2)

fig.suptitle('Overall title')

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Also note that `GridSpec(1, 3, wspace=1)` creates 3 subplots with a wide gap between each. `outer[2]` is unused in the code.

Comment: Yes I forgot to update when going from 1x3 grid to 1x2 grid. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: would you happen to know how I could set a title for the outer grid (a single main overall title) then a title per each inner grid (2 titles, one above each inner grid in this example)?

Comment: Currently I am doing something very hacky like `fig.suptitle(f"Main Title\n {'Title Image 1':^50} {'Title Image2':^50}", x=0.5, y=1.2)`

Comment: I updated the code with a way to add titles, but it is also quite hacky. If you don't need multiple rows for the outer level, your approach is certainly valid. In general, once you go beyond the standard layout of `plt.subplots`, you'll have to control positions manually.

Comment: I see. Thank you!